# after_destroy to remove categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My code creates categories automatically upon creating a new instance of a model.  Here is the code for one of the models.

```
class Grow < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :category

after_create do
  Category.create(name: self.title)
end

before_destroy do
  Category.destroy(name: self.title)
end
```

end

The create works, but the destroy gives me this error

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: id.name: SELECT "categories".*
         FROM "categories" WHERE "id"."name" = 'My very first grow room' LIMIT 1
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Category.find_by(name: self.title).destroy
```

Bear in mind that destroy will trigger any callbacks on the Category you have triggered by, but delete does not

This is what ActiveRecord ([destroy](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/destroy)) is doing under the hood:

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb, line 2614
  def destroy
    unless new_record?
      connection.delete(
        "DELETE FROM #{self.class.quoted_table_name} " +
        "WHERE #{connection.quote_column_name(self.class.primary_key)} = #{quoted_id}",
        "#{self.class.name} Destroy"
      )
    end

    @destroyed = true
    freeze
  end
```

Comment: That worked great, thanks for the quick response!  I went with the delete option because I dont need to trigger extra callbacks when I just want to delete it from the record.